# using while loop to read files

Tags: python

I have 200 files, from which I wanna choose the second column. I wanna store the second column of each file in a list called "colv". I wanna have colv[0]=[second column of the first file. colv[1] be the second column of the second file and so on.
I write this code, but it does not work, in this code colv[0] is the first number of the second column of the first file. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue:

```
colv = []
i = 1
colvar = "step7_1.colvar"
while os.path.isfile(colvar):
    with open(colvar, "r") as f_in:
        line = next(f_in)
        for line in f_in:
            a = line.split()[1]
            colv.append(a)
    i+=1
    colvar = "step7_%d.colvar" %i
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a file `step7_2.colvar`? The loop stops as soon as it gets to a missing file.

Comment: Do you want to skip the missing files and look for the rest? Use a `for` loop instead of `while` loop.

Comment: yes i am sure that i have all the files

Comment: If there are multiple lines in the file, how do you want the second column of all the lines to be stored in a single list element? Should it be a nested list?

Comment: yes it should be a nested list like this: [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]. But my code is not generating such a thing for me. Do you know how can i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Pandas' [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) since you mention that the data has a table-like structure. In particular, you could use

```
import pandas as pd

colv = []
i = 1
colvar = "step7_1.colvar"
while os.path.isfile(colvar):
    df = pd.read_csv(colvar, sep=',')
    colv.append(list(df[df.columns[1]]))
    
    i+=1
    colvar = "step7_%d.colvar" %i
```

It returned

```
>colv
[[5, 6, 7, 8], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

for my vanilla sample files `step7_%d.colvar`.

You might need to adjust the separator character with `sep`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to get the 2nd element of all the lines into a list.

```
colv = []
i = 1
colvar = "step7_1.colvar"
while os.path.isfile(colvar):
    with open(colvar, "r") as f_in:
        readline(f_in) # skip 1st line
        data = [line.split()[1] for line in f_in]
        colv.append(data)
    i+=1
    colvar = "step7_%d.colvar" %i
```